# Prolog Predicates with A Variable Amount of Terms

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to make a small `Prolog` program that can turn a `term` into `html` content.

```
render_term(html(Head, Body), Output) :-
    OpenHtmlTag = '<html>',
    render_term(Head, HeadOutput),
    string_concat(OpenHtmlTag, HeadOutput, OutputWithHead),

    render_term(Body, BodyOutput),
    ClosedHtmlTag = '</html>',
    string_concat(BodyOutput, ClosedHtmlTag, Output).

...

render_term(h2(Content), Output) :-
    string_concat('<h2>', Content, ContentWithOpenTag),
    string_concat(ContentWithOpenTag, '</h2>', Output).
```

A problem arises when I try to implement a `render_term` predicate for `<body>` tag.

`body.html`

```
<body>
    <main> ... </main>
    <h1> content </h1>
    ...
</body>
```

`body.prolog`

```
render_term(body([Tag1 | Tail]), Output) :- ...
```

Unlike the `<html>` tag, the `<body>` tag must take in a variable number of arguments.

I tried to decompose a list in the example above, but it failed. I have heard of the `univ` operator but couldn't get it to work right.

```
render_term(body(Terms), Output) :-
    Terms =.. [Tag1, Tail],
    ...
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: "must take in a variable number of arguments" - so treat `Terms` as a *list*. To represent the HTML tree structure ( https://javascript.info/dom-nodes ), the list elements could themselves be lists. Also - DCGs are far more elegant than `string_concat`.

Comment: How could you replace this with DCGs? I thought DCGs were for lexical analysis stuff

Comment: DCGs are very flexible, and perfect for structured text such as HTML, for both parsing and generating - intro: https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/dcg

Comment: What exactly are you doing? Is this homework, your own project? Which implementation are you using? At least SWI-Prolog has an extensive framework for generating HTML from Prolog terms, you should maybe study it. You could start reading [here](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=html//1). Study the state of the art before improving on it!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you didn't show us what your `body` terms look like. That would have been useful. Anyway, there are two obvious ways of doing this:

A one-argument `body` term whose single argument is always a list, for example:

```
body([main(...), h1(...), p(...), h1(...), p(...), p(...)])
```

In this case, you could process the list with a helper predicate `render_terms` (the plural of `render_term`):

```
render_term(body(Terms), Output) :-
    % ... render '<body>' ...
    render_terms(Terms, TermsOutput),
    % ... render '</body>', concat outputs into Output

render_terms([], "").
render_terms([Term | Terms], Output) :-
    render_term(Term, TermOutput),
    render_terms(Terms, TermsOutput),
    string_concat(TermOutput, TermsOutput, Output).
```

The alternative would be using `body` terms with an arbitrary number of arguments:

```
body(main(...), h1(...), p(...), h1(...), p(...), p(...))
```

You were on the right track with `=..`, but your problem was that you cannot match such a term with `body(Terms)` because this expects a single argument term, not arbitrarily many. You would need to pull the matching into the `=..` call itself:

```
render_term(BodyTerm, Output) :-
    BodyTerm =.. [body | Terms],
    % ... as above using render_terms
```

Overall, the first approach with a list of arguments is preferable.

As a general note, the approach using string concatenation is very verbose and will be slow. As a comment noted, you should look into using definite clause grammars (DCGs) for an approach that is simpler to write and that will execute faster.